# better to resize before or after layering in GD?

Tags: php, resize, gd, layer

I'm layering a number of png images using GD in PHP and then outputting a smaller version.

Which is more efficient, to `imagecopy` all of the layers and then `imagecopyresampled` the composite image onto a blank image of the desired size, or to start by creating a blank image of the desired size and then `imagecopyresampled` each layer onto the canvas?

Comment: Can't you just benchmark this?